# Connect git historys after cut

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history, git-history

My two repos are from the same project. I make a history cut after commit `3` and work now only with Repo **ProjectnameWorking**.

***git log* Repo "ProjectnameArchiv":**

```
30114b2afac5d1c5a968441151ee8f91fc015ff3 4
9aa472d04501a14b5b704fde32445461f99f539a 3
1d0e5abe5daf60c0d86819938ba1aefd44b87ff5 2
766f4880e8ccf61bdc718dfae62466f800ae8119 1
```

***git log* Repo "ProjectnameWorking":**

```
2932c4b8ea681f0a97bf151ccc46d2044e8e5a50 5
27ec1a4618f1bf0025b8ba83fd69c2607cdf78d4 4
```

---

Is there a way to connect later both historys & projectfiles to one?

***git log* Repo "Projectname"**

```
2932c4b8ea681f0a97bf151ccc46d2044e8e5a50 5
27ec1a4618f1bf0025b8ba83fd69c2607cdf78d4 4
9aa472d04501a14b5b704fde32445461f99f539a 3
1d0e5abe5daf60c0d86819938ba1aefd44b87ff5 2
766f4880e8ccf61bdc718dfae62466f800ae8119 1
```

---

**Edit:**

- Commit 4 at  Repo "ProjectnameArchiv" - get new hash from cut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is possible, but the SHAs of one of the projects will change:

- Create a common remote repository:

  ```
  /some/other/path> git init . --bare
  ```
- Create a branch in `ProjectnameArchiv` at `9aa472d04501a14b5b704fde32445461f99f539a` and push it to the remote:

  ```
  ProjectnameArchiv> git branch merge-base 9aa472d04501a14b5b704fde32445461f99f539a
  ProjectnameArchiv> git remote add origin file:///some/other/path
  ProjectnameArchiv> git push --all
  ```
- Do the same in the other repo but fetch instead of push:

  ```
  ProjectnameWorking> git branch working-top 2932c4b8ea681f0a97bf151ccc46d2044e8e5a50
  ProjectnameWorking> git remote add origin file:///some/other/path
  ProjectnameWorking> git fetch origin
  ```
- *cherry-pick* the first working commit into the archive branch:

  ```
  ProjectnameWorking> git checkout -b archive origin/merge-base
  ProjectnameWorking> git cherry-pick 9aa472d04501a14b5b704fde32445461f99f539a
  ```
- If you have only a few commits you can continue cherry-picking, but for a larger number, *rebase-ing* the rest of the work branch onto the archive branch is faster:

  ```
  ProjectnameWorking> git rebase --onto archive 9aa472d04501a14b5b704fde32445461f99f539a working-top
  ```

  You might add git’s `-i` option to check what it is doing before it starts, and interrupt the process if something went wrong.

After that, the changes of the working repository are added to the archive repository but they get new SHAs.

Comment: if i try git checkout -b archive origin/merge-base i get the Error : _fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'archive' at the same time.
Did you intend to checkout 'origin/merge-base' which can not be resolved as commit?_

Comment: @Gh0stscript what is the output of `git branch --list --remotes`?

Comment: ProjectnameWorking> git branch --list --remotes
_origin/master_

Comment: when pushing the archive you might want to add the `--all` switch. I updated the answer.

Comment: i realized that commit 4 is in both projects(update question)...so i dont know if the error from _git rebase --onto archive 9aa472d04501a14b5b704fde32445461f99f539a working-top_ came from this. Error: CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in Test.txt
Patch failed at 0001 4
The copy of the patch that failed is found in: .git/rebase-apply/patch

Comment: a _git rebase --skip_ is working, now i had a working-top log with all commits. Thanks a lot :)