# Merge/rebase two git repos which share files into one

Tags: git

I have a long going git project which havn't had commits for long time. 
Then a new developer got a checkout and created a new git init with those files, and start committing stuff.

How is it possible to merge and keep his commit log into the original repository?

It seems a bit hard when it does not share any commit.

I have tried to add the new project into a new remote branch, and then merge and rebase, but no log. It does gives conflicts because files are added in the init commit of the new project.

*Update:*

So it kind of works, if I take cherry pick commits other that the new initial commits. However, the initial commit was done directly on prod server, which might have changes for the old repo version. So I need to create a commit first with those changes.

[image: Git history of new init]

Comment: Show what you tried. Setting up one as a remote is the expected procedure. If it failed, you have to be very detailed.

Comment: What if you ignore his initial commit, and `git cherry-pick` his second commit?  Does that work?  If so, can you just cherry pick all his commits after the first one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect git historys after cut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51532479/connect-git-historys-after-cut)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I clone into a non-empty directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411031/how-do-i-clone-into-a-non-empty-directory)